# ¿Se puede hacer conexión a MySQL desde C# con variables contenidas en un archivo?

Tags: c#, sql, mysqli

Soy un novato en C#, estoy comenzando y tengo una inquietud. **¿Se puede tener una archivos con los datos de conexión (Ip del servidor, Puerto, usuario, contraseña, etc.) y desde mi programa principal leerlo y pasarlo a la clase que me hace la conexión a la base de datos?**.

El archivo puede ser, por ejemplo un archio .INI o un XML. El detalle es que si yo pretendo instalar mi programa en varios servidores puede que me toque cambiar algunos datos y en especial a los equipos clientes. Agradezco comentarios.

Comment: si tienes acceso al archivo desde tu aplicacion si, puedes leer cualquier dato contenido en el y establecer conexiones si quieres.

Comment: Como dice @MiguelZarate, si se puede, pero es mejor utilizar los archivos de configuracion. por ejemplo: el app.config o el web.config, cual se tu caso.

Comment: Una ventaja que le veo a los archivos de configuracion es que son facil de obtener la informacion y si tienes datos sensitivos tambien se pueden encriptar.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, si yo utilizo el app.config, **¿el dato contenido puede estar encriptado?** logicamente, posterior a la lectura dentro de mi programa, lo desencripto, ¿esto se puede? Gracias.

Comment: claro que se puede encriptar valores de configuracion [encryption](https://magenic.com/thinking/encrypting-configuration-sections-in-net)

Comment: Gracias todos, ya estoy códificando las clases para uitlizar y probrar la conexión. Muy amables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para definir la configuracion de conexion a la db no se usa ningun archivo, menos aun un .ini

Debes usar el `app.config` del proyecto

Como explico aqui, en la primer parte

[Archivos de Configuración - Una introducción (1/3)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/07/archivos-de-configuracion-una.html)

defines

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y dentro de este

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Referencia la libreria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces en el codigo usas

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
```

Encriptar una seccion de configuracion requiere algunos pasos adicionales.

Usar la linea de comando, con `aspnet_regiis` para que encripte la seccion de configuracion, si es raro usar algo de `asp.net` pero es el que se aplica en estos casos.

[Encrypt and Decrypt Connection String in App.Config file](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Connection-String-in-AppConfig-file.aspx)

Como observaras se usa el comando

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "<Path of the Folder containing the App.Config file>"
```

Comment: Gracias Leando por la respuesta. La sugerencia me sirve, voy a realizar los cambios que requiero para que me trabaje con base en tus comentarios.